# Liquibase -Drop Table Best Practice

Tags: database, devops, liquibase, cicd, drop

in a DevOps (CI/CD) scenario, when Liquibase is triggered by a specific step of a pipeline, is a good practice that Liquibase drops all application ( microservice ) DB tables and recreate all DDL/DML using changesets (only for test and pre-production environment) ?\

If it is, why?

thanks

Comment: No, it should always go only forward, so apply all to the existing database. I wouldn't do drop/recreate. That could be tested with integration tests not on real environment. Or it could be tested in ci/cd against empty databases (you can use testcontainers).

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase is designed to maintain database model consistency between all environments.
And when you drop database in one of them you break that consistency as you wouldn't want to drop production database as well. Check out [Roll Back the Database or Fix Forward?](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/roll-back-database-fix-forward) article

If you need to drop some table, you should write additional `<dropTable>` changeSet.

If you need to test initial application deployment on an empty database, you can always use containers, as suggested by @bilak in the comments.

Comment: Actually in test environment every time a CI is triggered, Liquibase drops all and recreate all DDL and DML using changesets. In this way i remove all useless data written for test purpose or tables created but not accepted in superior env., ensuring that i always have a clean DB. Do you thing is a bad way to operate?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the database you use for your integration tests should be **ephemeral** so that your pipeline always starts from a clean slate. The popular way to accomplish that is to use [TestContainers](https://testcontainers.com) in your tests.

However, for some CI systems it is near impossible to use something like TestContainers because the pipeline itself is already executing in Docker and docker-in-docker is a PiTA. As an alternative some CI systems, like GitLab, provides you optionally with an ephemeral database service which will exist throughout the lifetime of the pipeline execution. It may also be that the database server you want to test against is simply of a more permanent nature.

In any case, if the database server is shared between different tests, then you have another problem, namely that of **test isolation**.

If you are using Spring Boot, then you can solve that with [Pre-Liquibase](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase), specifically about [creating schema on-the-fly for each test case](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase#pre-liquibase-used-for-test-isolation). It doesn't have a feature to clean up after itself, but if your database server is killed when the CI pipeline then that doesn't matter.

Hope you can use those ideas.